# All visual studio installers crash and visual build tools won't work either

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, node-gyp

I wouldn't be screwing around with Visual Studio at all if nodejs and specifically node-gyp didn't depend on it.  All I am really trying to do is install the active-win npm package, but because it had a window API dependency I needed to run node-gyp and that sent me down this rabbit hole.

For whatever reason, the 2015 visual studio installer crashes, but I simply used `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`.  It successfully installed build tools, however, the issue here persists.

The was also a smaller error where node-gyp try to look in /v120/ despite the msmversion being set to 2015, I fixed this by setting the VCTargetsPath location.

Here is the full error from running npm i -D active-win at this point:

```
C:\Users\Henry Hunt\Documents\GitRep\ludite>npm install -D active-win

> iconv@2.3.5 install C:\Users\Henry Hunt\Documents\GitRep\ludite\node_modules\iconv
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Henry Hunt\Documents\GitRep\ludite\node_modules\iconv>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "N:\Nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "N:\Nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\Henry Hunt\Documents\GitRep\ludite\node_modules\iconv\build\iconv.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported p
roject "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that
 the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (N:\Nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "N:\\Nodejs\\node.exe" "N:\\Nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Henry Hunt\Documents\GitRep\ludite\node_modules\iconv
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok

> ref-napi@1.4.2 install C:\Users\Henry Hunt\Documents\GitRep\ludite\node_modules\ref-napi
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Henry Hunt\Documents\GitRep\ludite\node_modules\ref-napi>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "N:\Nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "N:\Nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\Henry Hunt\Documents\GitRep\ludite\node_modules\ref-napi\node_modules\node-addon-api\src\nothing.vcxproj(20,3)
: error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.pro
ps" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (N:\Nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "N:\\Nodejs\\node.exe" "N:\\Nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Henry Hunt\Documents\GitRep\ludite\node_modules\ref-napi
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN @date-io/date-fns@1.3.11 requires a peer of date-fns@2.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: iconv@2.3.5 (node_modules\iconv):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: iconv@2.3.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ref-napi@1.4.2 (node_modules\ref-napi):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ref-napi@1.4.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ active-win@6.0.0
added 2 packages from 3 contributors, updated 1 package and audited 10413 packages in 6.338s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The version of build tools installed is 2015 and the folder its entering \V140\ is actually where the config appears to be stored.  The one missing file is Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props.  I have not been able to find anyone who had the same problem.  There are plenty of people with the same error, but in resolving their issue Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props is simply in some other directory.  This is the directory it should be in, it's not there.

How do I fix this?

Comment: UPDATE: I've installed Visual Studio 2019 and started using that install instead of the npm install_build_tools version.  After setting npm config's msvs_version = "2019" and msbuild_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe" most of my problems were fixed accept for one.

Comment: Running npm rebuild

Comment: ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.ToolsetLocation.props(50,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\ 
Microsoft\VC\v160Platforms\x64\Platform.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\Users\henhen724\Documents\GitRep\ludite\node_modules\iconv\build\iconv.vcxpr 
oj]
gyp ERR! build error 
```

Comment: In the words whatever registers stores C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\ Microsoft\VC\v160 has a missing \ and that appears to be the only thing stopping this from running.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I downloaded Visual Studio 2019 instead of using node_build_tools.  Even though node build tools claimed to have installed the actual C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild did not have any of the files npm needed in it.  After I fully uninstalled the previous Visual Studio's installer, the 2019 installer worked fine.

Well, after that it turned out to be pretty easy.  Here's what you need to do:

- `npm config set msvs_version 2019`
- `npm config set msbuild_path "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"`
- Then set the VCTargetsPath local environment variable, and no you cannot simply set this in npm config or in the registry.  I tried that.

  1. CMD

     - `SET VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\`
     - (don't forget the last backslash it won't work if you do)
  2. GitBash or other bash like shells

     - `VCTargetsPath="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Microsoft\\VC\\v160\\"`

Note:  Though Visual Studio will let you choose where you install your Visual Studio IDE Folder, which is just the default place where the IDE saves files to, at any path or drive on the computer, the actual Microsoft Visual Studio folder above is always installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\, so don't alter that.