# iconv.node Module Error despite node-gyp rebuild saying OK

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-gyp, iconv

I'm trying to use the active-win npm module in a React project and it seems like one of its dependencies, the iconv package keeps throwing errors.
This is the error I'm getting:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '../build/Debug/iconv.node' in
> 'D:\Projects\project\myapp\node_modules\iconv\lib'

This is continuing despite the fact that I've gone into the iconv folder and run

> node-gyp rebuild

with this as the result:

> Generating code   All 565 functions were compiled because no usable
> IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.   Finished generating
> code   iconv.vcxproj ->
> D:\Projects\project\myapp\node_modules\iconv\build\Release\iconv.node
> gyp info ok

gyp info is ending with 'ok' which should mean I'm good, but I'm not.

I'm at wits' end and have no idea how to solve this. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: The other possibility is that active-win is incompatible with React, but I haven't found anything online indicating this is the case. If it is indeed true, can someone confirm this for me, and give me suggestions on what else I should use if I want to incorporate it into my project?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I have been able to solve it using the instruction of the following url:
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md

Answer (score 0):

**iconv** can not build with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 so you need to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, I flowed this answer and I manage to build the **active-win** in windows 10 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59005082/9381803